# validar regExp en javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy trantando de validar un correo en un input en html usando regexp, no logro que me lo valide correctamente que fallo podría estar realizando ? Cuando quito el foco siempre me sale email incorrecto aunque coloque bien el patrón.

```js
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener('focusout', function () {
   
  var regExpEmail = new RegExp('^w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$');
  if (regExpEmail === true) {
    console.log('Email correcto');
  } else {
  console.log('Email incorrecto');
  }
```

Comment: qué error te da?, qué email te falla? has probado https://regexr.com/?

Comment: el if /else, creo que no coge el if y directamente sale el else todo el rato como si el if no funcionara correctamente.

Comment: a bote pronto, veo un fallo, pero igual no es lo que tu tienes en mente... hay correos electrónicos que terminan en .co.uk (emails de Reino Unido). Según veo tu regular expression no pasarían

Comment: estoy probando el típico ejemplo de nombre@correo.com, no necesito nada mas complicado

Comment: nombre@correo.co.uk no pasaría y probablemente nombre+test@correo.com tampoco

Comment: no no solo necesito nombre@correo.com nada mas dificil

Comment: No reinventes la rueda, con [emailregex](https://emailregex.com) tienes lo que buscas. A veces es mejor usar las herramientas ya desarrolladas por expertos, y en el campo de las expresiones regulares hay bastantes expertos y muchos coinciden que el patrón que se muestra en esa web es 99.99% funcional. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque en las respuestas ya se solucionen el problema, quiero dar mi aporte observando tu codigo:

1. Esta mal escrito, porque falta al final cerrar `})`
2. La exprecion regular que estas usando tambien esta mal porque valida incorrectamente un correo segun [regexr](https://regexr.com/)
3. `RegExp` no devuelve un booleano porque es una funcion constructor [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)
4. Para validar un `RegExp` se utiliza el `test()` donde esta ultima si devuelve un `booleano`

Como desconozco aun usar expreciones regulares, usare un ejemplo para validar un correo usando esto [validar-correo-usando-exprecion-regular](https://davidburgos.blog/expresion-regular-para-validar-emails-en-javascript/)

```js
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
  var regExpEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/.test(e.target.value);
  
  if (regExpEmail) {
    console.log("Email correcto");
  } else {
    console.log("email incorrecto");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!! ha sido el unico que me ha logrado funcionar :)

Answer (score 1):

Estas comparando la expresion regular con un true, eso no funciona, debes comparar el valor del input con la expresion regular usando test.

```
 <input type="email" id="email" />
        <script>
          document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
            var regExpEmail = new RegExp("^w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$");
            console.log(e.target.value); // Valor actual del input
            if (regExpEmail.test(e.target.value)) {
              console.log("Email correcto");
            } else {
              console.log("email incorrecto");
            }
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: nose si he hecho algo diferente pero ahora ya funciona correctamente, lo que si coloco incorrectamente el correo funciona igualmente y no sale email incorrecto

Comment: Lo siento, modifico la respuesta, la forma correcta no era con search, sino con test, expresionRegular.test(valor)

Answer (score 1):

Según https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp estás creando un objeto RegExp, no un boolean, cuando compruebas (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp), estás igualando RegExp a true, en valor y tipo cosa que no funciona, porque true es boolean.
Lo que tienes que hacer es comparar la expresion regular con el email y si es identico o no ir a un lado u otro.
Tienes ejemplos de lo que quieres hacer en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603015/check-whether-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-js

Answer (score 0):

Como bien responde Iria, estas comparado `regExpEmail === true` lo que siempre sera falso, ya que al usar `===` estas comparando un dato varchar con uno boolean.

De todas formas no estas comparando ningun email con la expresion regular. La expresion regular `^w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$` segun [reger.com](https://regexr.com/) no valida `nombre@correo.com`. He usado esta expresion regular, y si que funciona como creo que esperas `^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$`

```js
   
  var regExpEmail = new RegExp('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$');
  var email = "nombre@correo.com";
  if (regExpEmail.test(email)) {
    console.log('Email correcto');
  } else {
  console.log('Email incorrecto');
  }
```